# How to make a "for loop" synchronous in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I am trying to get the user details from backend server, i am getting the details but not in order, Details are getting mixed to each other.
My controller code is here

```
function addRecentDetailsToDestination(array) {
             for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                 var value = array[i];
           userService.RetrieveRecentEduDetail(value.destinationId, function (rResponse) {
                     if (rResponse.success) {
                         value.destRecentEducationAvailable = true;
                         value.destRecentEducationName = rResponse.data.educationName;

                         userService.RetrieveCollege(rResponse.data.colCode, function (cResponse) {
                             if (cResponse.success) {
                                 value.destRecentCollegeName = cResponse.data.colName;
                             } else {

                             }
                         });

                     } else {
                         value.destRecentEducationAvailable = false;

                     }
                     alert(console.log(value.destRecentEducationName));
                 });

                 userService.RetrieveRecentProfessionDetail(value.destinationId, function (response) {
                     if (response.success) {
                         value.destRecentProfessionAvailable = true;
                         value.destRecentProfessionRole = response.data.professionRole;
                         value.destRecentProfessionCompany = response.data.professionCompany;


                     } else {
                         value.destRecentProfessionAvailable = false;
                     }
                 });
               });
             }
         }
```

This code is working fine, but not getting proper result, please help me
and i am calling the function like this

```
 userService.RetrieveUserConnectionsBySourceId(userId, function (response) {

                 if (response.success) {
                     $scope.userConnectionsBySource = response.data;

                     addRecentDetailsToDestination($scope.userConnectionsBySource);

                 } else {
                     FlashService.Error(response.message);
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default behavior of Asynchronous execution in JavaScript with AngularJS you need to use `$q` promises. This would give you the control on calling the service methods and based on the result from promises `($q)` you can control the execution behavior.

Comment: can you explain how should i implement $q promises little bit?